# What is the best currently proven bounds on prime gaps?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

I did some digging around on the internet but I found tons of different equations on both lower and upper bounds for the largest possible prime gap g(n). I was wondering what are currently the best bounds that have been proven.

Comment: The wikipedia page seems up-to-date: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Answer (score 9):

I believe the best unconditional lower bound on $G(X)$, the largest gap for primes less than $X,$ is the one by Ford, Green, Konyagin, Maynard and Tao, discussed at Tao's blog at

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/long-gaps-between-primes/

which is

$$
g(X) \gg \log X \frac{\log_2 X \log_4 X}
{\log_3 X}
$$
where $\log_2(\cdot)=\log \log((\cdot))$, etc.

And the best known upper bound is
$$
G(X)\ll \frac{X^{0.525}}{\log X}
$$
for $X$ large enough, due to Baker, Harman and Pintz.